# Transition to UITabBarController

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I need help with bug fix. I'm use segue to transit between ViewControllers.

I have `UITabBarController` with one `UIViewController`. When I click on button in my vc I move to second vc. My second vc doesn't have TabBar. (use segue). In my second vc I have button and `UIAlertController`. When I click on button or alert I must transit to first vc with TabBar, but my TabBar doesn't displayed. How to fix this ? I `don't` need to use `NavigationController`.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Поздравляю", message: "Тренировка окончена", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backSegue", sender: self) }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJfLH.png)

Comment: Can you please put your code of button action, where you are moving to second VC. And storyboard UI screenshot if possible ?

Comment: @VRAwesome for button I don't use code. segue -> show

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting the second ViewController modally add this to your UIAlertController action:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your `FirstViewController` from where you are moving to `NextController` via `segue`.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToFirst:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {

    UIViewController* sourceViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController;

    if ([sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
         NSLog(@"Coming from SECOND!");
    } else {
         NSLog(@"Handle Error");
    }
}
```

And go to storyboard, right click and hold and drag from `Button` on `NextController` to Exit responder.

[image: segue_1]

And you method name appears, connect to that.

[image: segue_2]

Please refer this answer : [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)